# HP laptop won't sleep/shut down

Tags: windows-10, drivers, sleep, shutdown, hp-envy

I have an HP Envy x360 laptop (15-u011dx) running the newest version of Windows 10. I recently replaced the battery in it, but my laptop is having issues with going to sleep and shutting down. After the computer is on for at least 30 minutes, trying to get it to sleep or shut down will result in the hard drive locking itself like it should, but then the CPU fan never turns off and the power button light stays on instead of blinking. I am not able to wake it up from sleep at this point, so I have to hold the power button for ~10 seconds and then turn it back on again.

I've tried a lot of things, such as changing the power/sleep settings around, installing new drivers/updates using HP Support Assistant, enabling a Cisco driver in device manager after reading the report generated by the "powercfg /batteryreport" command and installing a different version of the [Intel Management Engine Interface (MEI) Driver](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/94631-pc-wont-shutdown-sleep-black-screen-but-can-reboot-3.html)

Anyone know if there's anything else I can try or have any idea as to what's causing this issue? It's driving me crazy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had in the past a similar issue, it was related on the nvidia driver, but to me append only when wake-up from hibernate; 
More similar problem I had with a computer (quite old) of a friend, which won't shutdown like yours; 
solution for me at that time was install windows at 32bit even the CPU suport 64bit code. Really don't know the reason, but at that time with that computer was work.